# How to match finger prints in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, fingerprint, biometrics

I have an application that is about to change in order to validate users by their finger prints. Basically, the logon window will be redesigned to lose the login name and password fields. In their place, the window will wait until someone puts his/her finger on a fingerprint scanner connected to the workstation.

Since there are about 50,000 users, whose account data are stored in a Oracle server, the problem is what to save in the User table and how to select the correct user by using the fingerprint data instead the login name/password pair?

Comment: What does the fingerprint scanner output?  Just a photograph, or some kind of encoding?  Whatever it is you can store it in the database, possibly as a BLOB.  You will then need an algorithm that compares 2 of these and computes a likelihood of them being for the same person.  Oracle won't have that, you'll need to supply it.

Comment: The fingerprint scanner produces what is called a fingerprint template, which is an array of (for the model I will use) 384 bytes. Since Oracle will now provide a matching algorithm, I know I can write a PL/SQL function to compute it, but in this case it's correct to say that no indexes will be used during a select, right?

Comment: You can have a function-based index in Oracle.  But I think the problem is that you are not looking for an exact match (`fingerprint_column = :fingerprint_value`) but a best probable match (`max(match_probability(fingerprint_column, :fingerprint_value))`).  So if using indexes at all you will be full-scanning them.

Comment: fingerprint comparison is a complex topic.  Likely there is no patience for failed authentications.  You need a good library, possibly here http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching fingerprint template (or image) is not just a compare of byte array. Please read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition

To match 50,000 users (How many finger are enrolled for each user) you need an [AFIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_fingerprint_identification)

There's a lot of AFIS provider as:

- http://www.neurotechnology.com/megamatcher.html
- http://au.nec.com/en_AU/solutions/security-and-public-safety/biometrics/afis-fingerprint-identification-features.html
- http://www.innovatrics.com/products
- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/afis/
- http://www.m2sys.com/automated-fingerprint-identification-system-afis/

And an open-source solution:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/

Comment: Your answer helped me to keep investigating the case and guided me to what seems to be the exact answer to my needs: http://www.biometrics.org/bc2002/2_Sundara%20Brief.pdf. Because you pointed the concept of AFIS, that helped me to reach that document, I will consider your answer as the one. Thanks!!!