# Compare fingerprint on SQL, in host it is too slow?

Tags: database, oracle, performance, time-complexity, fingerprint

I am using Oracle with java to store templates of fingerprints.

I have a problem when the number of templates in the Data Base increases up to 45000, the application becomes slow.

I used threads for parallel comparison, the application becomes faster but still slow.

The question is: can I compare the template with a fingerprint sample in the server, with a `SQL` command or something?

The format of the template is the `blob`.

Comment: Fingerprint comparison is very complex. Have you read [this previous question (link)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34329952/146325) It has some potentially useful links about implementing AFIS. I'm not going to close as a duplicate in case other people have more up-to-date suggestion.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @GhostCat I corrected the grammar, please check if it is correct or not.

Comment: Sure, that looks good.

Comment: If the data to be compared is entirely in the database, Yes it's likely that a databsae side comparison will be faster for a large amount of records for a non complex comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are doing 1:N matching. Suggest to do classification before matching. You may follow below references for different FP types.

[8 Most Common Fingerprint Patterns](http://www.touchngoid.com/8-common-fingerprint-patterns/)

[What are different types of fingerprint with their rarity to find?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-different-types-of-fingerprint-with-their-rarity-to-find)

After classify the data, you could limit down the volume of data being matching. Another, you could have custom classification such as region, gender, demographic and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do the comparison like string comparison in any language including in SQL. It is possible, only if you have the same fingerprint image again and again. But in the reality, When you have the fingerprint two times, both the images will be different from each other with little bit position change, angle change, and quality of the scan. So String comparison is not possible.

All the scanners do provide the SDK for capturing the fingerprint and comparing them (1:1) which you can use for developing the desktop application. If you need to compare the scanned images at the server, then you need to implement your own Automatic Finger Identification algorithm or you have to use third party services such as

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)